# MATLAB - Matrix Combinations Unique Columns

Tags: matlab, unique

I'm fairly new to MATLAB and I am trying to find an efficient method of solving the following problem.

I have a matrix of 559 rows and 4 columns that I want to generate all the possible subsets containing 16 rows (preserving the row structure) such that each of the 4 columns contain unique values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a very general question, what did you try so far? Can there be gaps in the row numbers (e.g. row 1, 3, 5, 7, ...)? Are the final matrices 16x4 of size?

Comment: My first approach was to use for loops and test whether the columns were all unique. Yes there can be gaps in the row numbers. Correct the final matrices should be 16x4.

Comment: If you need to first generate all combinations of 16 rows out of 559 and then discard the ones with non-unique columns, you would need to loop through 3e30 elements , for reference matlab loops through 3e8 elements in about a second (on my machine), so it would take you 1e22 seconds to do the full loop, the universe is about 5e17 seconds old

Comment: Hence why I am asking for assistance.